# How can hive load data from csv?

Tags: apache, csv, hadoop, load, hive

I want to implement `apache hive` and I want to load the data from `csv file` to `hive table`. So, here's the problem :

my `csv file` generated by `SQL Server` in it's structure have " `sign`, and it's become something like `"04748/09","2248559","2248559","2009-12-03 00:00:00"`. So how can I only get the value without the " `sign` ?

Thanks a lot, I need your suggestions......

Comment: you know, remove the " in the file? if you have notepad++ you press CTRL + H and then search for " and leave the replace with blank and then replace all.

Comment: hahaha thanks bro, I don't think right that before, but I want to ask again, how can I ignore the first line when import on hive like an mysql import?

Thanks

Comment: you simply remove in the csv text file what you do not want imported. CSV is nothing more than txt. you can just edit it, save it and done.

Answer (score 0):

problem mention in your comment-how can I ignore the first line when import on hive like an mysql import? 
From Hive v0.13.0, you can use skip.header.line.count. You could also specify the same while creating the table. For example:

```
Create external table testtable (name string, message string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' location '/testtable'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP (f1 STRING, f2 String, f3 String, f4 String) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1");

load data local inpath 'test.csv'
overwrite into table TEMP;
```